# Se puede utilizar condicional if dentro de success en Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, if

Se puede utilizar una condicional if para validar el resultado de una variable?, algo asi como:

```
$("#update").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "ruta/al/archivo/uploadFac.php",
                type: "POST",
                data:  new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data){
                    if(var != 0){
                    $('#upload').modal('hide');
                    $('#Fac').modal('hide');
                    }else{
                        alert("ERROR");
                    }
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });
          });
        });
```

Donde la variable "var" es una variable que obtengo del script uploadFac.php con el cual se hizo la peticion, se puede hacer eso??

Comment: Si se puede :D! Intentalo, no veo que error tengas

Comment: Siempre que devuelvas un valor que sea compatible con esa comparación..

Comment: Si, el chiste es que no se como obtener las variables que arroja ese script, no se cual es la forma de hacerlo

Comment: Hola fernando en el `success` de tu `Ajax` puede implementar el `if` que deseas, solo tienes que evaluar la variable `data` que es la que tiene la respuesta al servidor de tu peticion `ajax`

Comment: En el archivo `uploadFac.php` debes enviar el valor de alguna forma, por ejemplo en un JSON, luego en el success lo recuperas y los comparas. Supongamos que en el php tu haces un echo `{"dato": 1};`... en el `success`  parseas la respuesta y  obtienes el valor mediante : `var dato=data.dato;` y lo comparas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La estructura de AJAX es un objeto, esto nos da mucha flexibilidad para hacer y deshacer. A lo que me refiero es que, el nodo `success` almacena una función anónima, y se comporta como cualquier otra, puedes meter cualquier tipo de código dentro. `IF, WHILE, FOR`, Incluso llamar otro AJAX (Para esto sería mejor el uso de `promises` y/o el método `.when` de Jquery)

Te dejo otra forma de cómo puedes armar tu AJAX

```js
$(function(){
  
  var llamarAjax = function(){
    //Aquí declaras el objeto que pasarás como parámetro
    var ajax = {};
    ajax.url = 'mi_url.py';
    ajax.method = 'POST';
    ajax.data = {
      dato1: 'dato1',
      dato2: 'dato2'};
    ajax.success = function(respuesta){
      console.log(respuesta);
      //Inclusive puedes volver a invocar otro ajax
      //llamarAjax();
    };
    ajax.error = function(xhr,err){
     //Aquí mandará error por que no está permitido el uso de AJAX en snippets
      console.log(err);
    };
    
    //Aquí pasas el objeto AJAX
    $.ajax(ajax);
  }
  
  $(document).on('click','#foo',function(){
    llamarAjax();
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Llamada!" id="foo">
```

Answer (score 1):

Claro que se puede, pero depende de que tipo de valor vas a devolver del back al front, si vas a enviar un objeto `json` sería así:

```
$("#update").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ruta/al/archivo/uploadFac.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.resultado != 0){
                $('#upload').modal('hide');
                $('#Fac').modal('hide');
            }else{
                alert("ERROR");
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
});
```

Pero si por el contrario vas a enviar un `string` o un valor numérico sería simplemente con el parámetro `data` que recibe el `success`:

```
$("#update").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ruta/al/archivo/uploadFac.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data != 0){
               $('#upload').modal('hide');
               $('#Fac').modal('hide');
            }else{
               alert("ERROR");
            }
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
});
```

Recuerda que el parámetro del método `success` es quien recibe los datos que devuelve el back..