# Posibilidad de utilizar un condicional en un success de Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Mi duda es si hay posibilidad de poder realizar un `if` en un success de Ajax, utilizando una varible (ejemplo, **opcion**), algo asi:

```
$("#lista").change(function(){
    var opcion = $("#lista").val();/*utilizar esta variable para realizar un if en success*/

    $.ajax({
        url: "...",
        method:"POST",
        data: ...,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType:'JSON',
        success: /*aqui deberia ir el if*/
    });
});
```

Por ejemplo, si `opcion = 1` realizar un:

```
if(opcion == 1)
{
   console.log(opcion);
}
```

He leido el siguiente [articulo: Se puede utilizar condicional if dentro de success en ajax](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168844/se-puede-utilizar-condicional-if-dentro-de-success-en-ajax) que tiene relación con mi pregunta, pero no es lo que busco.

Comment: La variable `opcion` es accesible en el ámbito en el que después llamarías a la función del `success`, así que sí. Para ellos debes usar una función anónima en la parte del `success`, como se hace en la pregunta del artículo que nos pasas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí, es posible, la manera de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
$("#lista").change(function(){
    var opcion = $("#lista").val();/*utilizar esta variable para realizar un if en success*/

    $.ajax({
        url: "...",
        method:"POST",
        data: ...,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType:'JSON',
        success: function(result){
            if(opcion == 1){
                console.log(opcion);
                console.log(result); //También puedes imprimir el resultado de la ejecución
            }
        }
    });
});
```